# Quantstrat won't work with ADX

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm running an R `quantstrat` based script, taken from [Backtesting Strategies with R](http://timtrice.github.io/backtesting-strategies/index.html)). It works. Until I add **ADX** as an indicator and signal. If so, then I get the following error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "ADXsig") : 
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

The supposed solution, discussed [here in quantstrattrader](http://quantstrattrader.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/nuts-and-bolts-of-quantstrat-part-ii) and [here in r.789695.n4.nabble.com](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/quantstrat-problems-adding-multiple-indicators-td4696777.html), would be to change the **ADX** `add.indicator` code from `x=quote(Cl(mktdata))` to `quote(Cl(mktdata)[,1])`. It doesn't work, maybe because ADX uses `HLC` rather than `Cl`, and `HLC` references three columns rather than only one. To be clear: changing `HLC=quote(HLC(mktdata))` to `quote(HLC(mktdata)[,1])` did not work.

Full working code below, and ADX code separately further below:

```
# INSTALL PACKAGES
# install.packages("devtools")
# require(devtools)
# install_github("braverock/FinancialInstrument")
# install_github("joshuaulrich/xts") 
# install_github("braverock/blotter")
# install.packages("quantstrat", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
# install_github("braverock/PerformanceAnalytics")

# LIBRARIES
library(quantstrat)   

# INITIAL SETUP
Sys.setenv(TZ = "EST")
currency('USD') 
start_date <- "2015-01-01"
end_date <- "2016-12-31"
init_equity <- 1e4 # $10,000
adjustment <- FALSE

# GET DATA
basic_symbols <- function() {symbols <- c("SPY")}
symbols <- basic_symbols()
getSymbols(Symbols = symbols, src = "google", index.class = "POSIXct", 
           from = start_date, to = end_date, adjust = adjustment)
stock(symbols,currency = "USD", multiplier = 1)

# DEFINE STRATEGY/PORTFOLIO/ACCOUNT NAMES
portfolio.st <- "Port.Luxor"
account.st <- "Acct.Luxor"
strategy.st <- "Strat.Luxor"

# REMOVE PRIOR STRATEGY/PORTFOLIO, INITIALIZE PORTFOLIO/ACCOUNT/STRATEGY, STORE STRATEGY
rm.strat(portfolio.st)
rm.strat(account.st)
initPortf(name = portfolio.st, symbols = symbols)
initAcct(account.st, portfolios = portfolio.st, initEq = init_equity)
initOrders(portfolio.st)
strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)

# INDICATORS & SIGNALS

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), 
                               n = 10),
              label = "nFast")

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st, 
              name = "SMA", 
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), 
                               n = 30), 
              label = "nSlow")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st,
           name="sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("nFast", "nSlow"),
                            relationship = "gte"),
           label = "long")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st,
           name="sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("nFast", "nSlow"),
                            relationship = "lt"),
           label = "short")

# TRADING RULES
add.rule(strategy = strategy.st,
         name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "long",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = 100,
                          ordertype = "stoplimit",
                          orderside = "long", 
                          threshold = 0.0005,
                          prefer = "High", 
                          TxnFees = -10, 
                          replace = FALSE),
         type = "enter",
         label = "EnterLONG")

add.rule(strategy.st, 
         name = "ruleSignal", 
         arguments = list(sigcol = "long", 
                          sigval = TRUE, 
                          orderside = "short", 
                          ordertype = "market", 
                          orderqty = "all", 
                          TxnFees = -10, 
                          replace = TRUE), 
         type = "exit", 
         label = "Exit2LONG")

# APPLY STRATEGY 
applyStrategy(strategy.st, portfolios = portfolio.st)
```

The error is produced when the following code (for **ADX** indicator & signal) is added. Even if not referenced by the strategy - its presence in the mktdata xts object is what produces the error. The presence of `add.indicator` by itself does not cause the error, its rather the presence of `add.signal` that does. Thinking the error may be caused by `add.signal` referencing `column = "ADX"`, but not knowing which ADX to reference because `add.indicator` created three ADX columns.

```
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="ADX", 
              arguments=list(HLC=quote(HLC(mktdata)), n=14), 
              label="ADX")

add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(column = "ADX",
                            threshold = 30,
                            relationship = "gt",      
                            cross = TRUE),            
           label = "ADXsig")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: changed `column = "ADX"` to `column = "ADX.ADX"`. As follows:

```
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="ADX", 
          arguments=list(HLC=quote(HLC(mktdata)), n=14), 
          label="ADX")

add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
       arguments = list(column = "ADX.ADX",
                        threshold = 30,
                        relationship = "gt",      
                        cross = TRUE),            
       label = "ADXsig")
```